# mantener valor de select seleccionado

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo un `select` que lo lleno con valores de la base de datos; cada valor está asociado a otra tabla. Lo que necesito es que la opción del `select` que aparezca seleccionada sea la que está asociada a la otra tabla.

```
<?php
 require('connect.php');
 for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  echo "<select name='in".($i+1)."'>";
  foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM base1') as $b1) {
   $sel = false;
   foreach ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base2 WHERE id='$id'") as $b2) {
    if ($b2['id']==$b1['id']) {
     $sel = true;
     break;
    }
   }
   echo "<option value='".$b1['id']."'>".$b1['dat']."</option>";
  }
 echo "</select><label>Dato ".($i+1)."</label>";
?>
```

Intenté con la variable `sel` mantenerlo seleccionado pero sólo me mantiene seleccionado el último valor asociado al `id`.

Un ejemplo de lo más aproximado del esquema que deseo lograr es como un `form` de preguntas asociadas a un usuario; hay varias preguntas pero solo una seleccionada por el usuario y ésta debe de aparecer selecionada en el `select`.

Agradeciendo de antemano su colaboración.

Comment: Necesitas usar un lenguaje del lado del cliente (como **Javascript**) para conseguir lo que necesitas. Con **PHP** y **HTML** solamente no puedes capturar el que el usuario haya seleccionado, como mucho puedes seleccionar el valor inicial del **select**.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción podría ser que si `$b2['id']==$b1['id']` le agregues el parámetro *selected* a ese elemento `<option>`, así:

```
<?php
 require('connect.php');
 for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  echo "<select name='in".($i+1)."'>";
  foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM base1') as $b1) {
   foreach ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base2 WHERE id='$id'") as $b2) {
    if ($b2['id']==$b1['id']) {
     echo "<option value='".$b1['id']."' selected>".$b1['dat']."</option>";
    }else{
     echo "<option value='".$b1['id']."'>".$b1['dat']."</option>";
   } 
  }
 echo "</select><label>Dato ".($i+1)."</label>";
?>
```

Comment: Hola pedro! eso lo hice pero la condicion $b2['id']==$b1['id'] se cumple 3 veces por lo que siempre me muestra el último valor asociado al id.

Comment: Hola, entonces te falta lógica, cómo quieres resolver el hecho de que $b1 tenga varias coincidencias con $b2? Qué quieres que haga la aplicación en ese caso? Qué seleccione la primer coincidencia? la última? Ninguna?